# Android update AppWidget ImageView src with a color

Tags: android

I'm trying to update an `ImageView` color in my `AppWidget` in my android application.

I have the hex decimal for my color, let's say `#ffffff`.

I'm sending a broadcast from an activity, triggering the widget `onReceive` method. The color is saved in `SharedPreferences`. This is how the `AppWidget onReceive()` looks like:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    RemoteViews widgetView = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
            R.layout.appwidget_homescreen);
    AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager
            .getInstance(context);

    // If the WidgetProvider was told to update the colors of the widget 
    if (intent.hasExtra("updateTheme")) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        String txtColorString = sharedPref.getString(
                PreferencesActivity.KEY_PREF_TXT_COLOR, "");
        int txtColor = Integer.parseInt(txtColorString);

        //I'm setting the color of the two text views here, working as intended. 
        widgetView.setTextColor(R.id.tvAppWidgetArtist,txtColor
                );
        widgetView.setTextColor(R.id.tvAppWidgetTitle,
                txtColor);

        //I want to set the color of the ImageView here, this is not working.
        widgetView.setTextColor(R.id.ivAppWidgetHS, txtColor);
        widgetView.setTextColor(R.id.ivAppWidgetVS, txtColor);

        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(new ComponentName(context,
                SongAppWidgetProvider.class), widgetView);
    }
    super.onReceive(context, intent);
}
```

The problem is that the color does not get updated. All it say is that there was a "Problem loading widget". Any ideas to why?

Comment: and the problem is ?

Comment: @Yazan The problem is that it's not working, I get a "Problem loading widget" on the homescreen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need just solid color image, you can just create it.

```
    Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(10, 10, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888); // size doesn't matter
    Canvas c = new Canvas(b);        
    c.drawColor(color);
    widgetView.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.imageView, b);
```

Answer (score 0):

A solid color for your widgetView

```
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(1,1, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
bitmap.eraseColor(Color.DKGRAY);
widgetView.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.imageView, bitmap);
```